# Can I verify signature using a precomputed hash in JavaCard 3.0.4

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I understood that in Javacard 3.0.5 there is an API to do so `verifyPreComputedHash()`. What about 3.0.4? Is it possible to first load a precomputed hash using `setInitialDigest()` then call `verify()`? Could anyone please give an example if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Padding used for hash algorithms such as SHA-1 and SHA-2 consists of bit padding and the size of the message. Unfortunately the padding is always necessary, and the size of the complete message is *unknown* before the last call to `signature` or `verify`.

Personally I've never understood this `setInitialDigest` method. It would only make sense if the data to be signed is split between the platform and the chip. Furthermore, it relies on a specific encoding of an *intermediate hash value* which is ill defined. For new designs / platforms I would certainly choose `verifyPreComputedHash`. But that's of little use if you're on anything before 3.0.5, I'm afraid.